# How to know iis is installed on windows 7 or not?

Tags: iis, windows-7, installation

I have installed IIS 8.0 Express as I can see that listed under Programs and Features.
I first run this "aspnet_regiis.exe -i" in Visual studio command prompt. Then typed inetmgr in RUN . It showed me an error "Windows cannot find inetmgrr .Make sure you typed the correctly, and then try again.".

Could anyone tell me how to resolve this issue ?
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to re-launch Visual Studio after installing it to make sure the command is picked up from the command prompt.

Comment: inetmgr is for the full IIS, not IIS express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to reinstall the IIS and install it again.

First check this:-

Go to Start->Run type inetmgr and press OK. If you get an IIS configuration screen. It is installed, otherwise it isn't.

You can also check ControlPanel->Add Remove Programs, Click Add Remove Windows Components and look for IIS in the list of installed components.

To Reinstall IIS.

Control Pane -> Add Remove Programs -> Click Add Remove Windows Components Uncheck IIS box Click next and follow prompts to UnInstall IIS. Insert your windows disc into the appropriate drive. Control Pane -> Add Remove Programs -> Click Add Remove Windows Components Check IIS box Click next and follow prompts to Install IIS.